# Get Cargo.toml version at runtime

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my `Cargo.toml` I have this block

```
[package]
name = "packagename"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me <abuse@gmail.com>"]
```

How can I fetch what [package].version is at runtime?

Comment: https://github.com/alexcrichton/toml-rs

Comment: The duplicate isn't matching, although it refers to the same solution. Thanks @Boiethios

Comment: You're welcome! FYI, the duplicate, contrary to what is written, does not apply to duplicate question, but to **duplicate answer**.

Comment: https://docs.rs/clap/2.9.3/clap/macro.crate_version!.html
Use `crate_version!()`

Comment: @Alinex Thanks, that's the best answer!

Comment: `option_env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")` is another alternative, see [`option_env!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html)

Comment: Or `let version = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");`